# JAVA - I want to get key and value from below text. There is "[key] value" format

Tags: regex, parsing, extract, regex-group

I want to get key and value from below text. There is `[key] value` format

For example,

```
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah
[abc-def] this is also value.
[BB]abcd defg
[CC] (can null)
```

Comment: what's output for that input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
\[(?<key>[^]]+)]\s*(?<value>[^\n]+(?:\n[^[][^\n]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ2wN2/1)

**Explanation:**
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`\s`: "whitespace character": space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab [sample](https://regex101.com/r/pD4dR7/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`(?: … )`: Non-capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bU9dN1/1)

Comment: i want output below.
AA -> "abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah"

abc-def -> this is also value.
BB -> abcd defg

CC -> (can null)

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
^\[([^]]+)\](.+)$
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/zB0xC0/1

### Explanation:

1. `^\[([^]]+)\]`: `^` is the beginning of a string. `()` is a capturing group. `[^]]+` is one or more of any character besides `]`.
2. `(.+)$`: `$` is the end of the string anchor. So basically it matches the rest of the string after the key.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
^(?:\[([^]]+)\])?(.*)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY1aO4/1)**